# How can I rotate multiple objects at the same time on mouse down click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At top

```
public Transform[] objects;
```

Then

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (isRotating == false))
            StartCoroutine(Rotate(5));
    }
```

And

```
IEnumerator Rotate(float duration)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        Quaternion startRot = objects[i].rotation;
        float t = 0.0f;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            isRotating = true;
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            objects[i].rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up); //or transform.right if you want it to be locally based

            yield return null;
        }
        objects[i].rotation = startRot;

        isRotating = false;
    }
}
```

It will rotate the objects but one by one the first one will rotate when it finish the next one and then the last one.

But I want to rotate them all at the same time.

Comment: Game development is based on the game loop. Basically the functions Update and Draw are called automatically, in a loop. To manipulate anything on the screen, usually you have to do the changes step by step, every time update is called (and you want to progress a game tick). And then Draw will draw whatever the current state is. In game development, loops are useless outside of itterating over a collection. Because there already is one loop to rule them all, that decides everything about the design.

Comment: @Christopher `Rotate` is a coroutine, and it yields control back to the main loop every iteration. The problem is that it doesn't change every object before it yields control. Tim Chang's answer shows how that can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Because `yield return null;` will let the game progress by a frame, you need to rotate all the objects between `yield return null;`.
- Use `t = Mathf.Min(t+Time.deltaTime, duration);` to stop exactly on 360 degrees.
- Use `yield return null` before you rotate, so that you set `isRotating = false;` the same frame the object rotates into place:

Altogether:

```
IEnumerator Rotate(float duration)
{
    float t = 0.0f;

    List<Quaternion> startRot = new List<Quaternion>();

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++) {
        startRot.Add(objects[i].rotation);
    }

    isRotating = true;

    while (t < duration)
    {
        yield return null;

        t = Mathf.Min(t+Time.deltaTime, duration);

        // foreach all object in one frame
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
        {
            objects[i].rotation = startRot[i] * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up); //or transform.right if you want it to be locally based
        }
    }   

    isRotating = false;   
}
```

Comment: After the last edit : Quaternion startRot = objects[i].rotation; This line don't have the i variable since it's out the loop.

Comment: No idea who upvoted this, but this will not work. There isn't going to be an `i` for `startRot = objects[i].rotation` outside the object loop. And even it there was, it's not going to work the same as OP's code intended. Reference `startRot` is being set inside the frame loop, while objects are  also being rotated inside the loop. See [my anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720317/1253136).

Answer (score 2):

## First problem:

Your "for each object" loop is outside the scope of your `yield return` call, so you are rotating one object across `duration`, and only after that rotating the next, and the next, and so on.

Your object loop must be within your `yield` loop, rather than outside it.

---

## Second problem:

As soon as rotations are done, you are setting the transform back to it's original rotation, with `objects[i].rotation = startRot;`. I don't know if that is the intended behaviour, but I don't see the point in that. If you want a looping rotation like that, just create an animation in unity, rather than animating through code.

If the rotation applied should stay, then this `rotation = startRot` command should be removed.

---

Don't have VS open right now, so coding this straight to SO, but unless my brain fails me (which woulnd't be too surprising), it should work:

```
IEnumerator Rotate(float duration) {
    isRotating = true;

    //Because we need the start rotations of every object, and we can't sample it after modifying rotations on the loop, we need to cache them prior.
    var rotationsTable = new Dictionary<Transform, Quaternion>();
    foreach (var obj in objects)
        rotationsTable[obj] = obj.rotation;

    //Then we do our time loop
    for (var t = 0f; t < duration; t = Mathf.MoveTowards(t, duration, Time.deltaTime)) {
        //And inside it, we do our rotations for every object in an objects' loop
        foreach (var obj in objects)
            obj.rotation = rotationsTable[obj] * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);
        //And skip to next frame / time-sample
        yield return null;
    }

    isRotating = false;
}
```

Comment: I like how you used `Mathf.MoveTowards` in the `for` loop header. Very nice answer.